# How to properly work with potassium HMDS

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

What is the proper procedure for working with KHMDS?  I would like to use it to deprotonate a compound and have a bottle of KHMDS in toluene.  Does it need to be handled under inert atmosphere?  And is it soluble in halogenated solvents?

Comment: Did you look at the MSDS or any other literature pertaining to KHMDS or would you rather have someone else give you the answer without you doing the work?

Comment: SDS's are nice but they tend to give safety instructions appropriate for tanker rail car volumes of material. (i.e. why do I need a respirator, face shield, apron, and gloves for everclear and table salt salt?)

Answer (score 2):

If you would look up the properties of KHMDS from a chemical supplier, you will find it will react violently with with water. So do keep it under inert atmosphere.

As for solubility, it is a non-nucleophilic base, so probable no substitution and addition like reactions will occur. I wont suspect it will be a problem there.

A comment on the use though. If you plan to use this, explore the dangers and possibilities of a substance like this a bit further than asking it here. For safety considerations. Look up the MSDS sheets from your supplier and be sure to only use this in a properly equipped lab.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I checked the msds right after posting the question and read up on it and was able to carry the reaction out successfully.  Thanks for your response.